# VBA - user input of row value to use in a cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to copy and paste a certain section of a row to another sheet. I'm getting the user to input the row they want the copy/paste to work from.

I've created a variable (`Dim c`) for the user to input the row value, and want to use that variable in a range, but don't know how.

E.g.

```vb
Range("C5:I5").Copy Range("C45:I45")
```

In the first step of this I want the '5' to be replaced by variable `c`, but how do I call that variable in this statement?

Tried `Range("C(Val(c)):I(Val(c))")`, but that hasn't worked.

Apologies for rookie errors, but I'm fairly new to VBA.

Comment: Try `Dim c As Long`, followed by `c = 5` then use `Range("C" & c & ":I" & c).Copy Range("C45:I45")`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it eventually using this -

Range("C" & c & ":I" & c)

Comment: What did you try with this pseudo answer? Did you copy the solution from my comment, placed three minutes before it?

Comment: @FaneDuru I found it on the web, the came back and posted. Your response probably didn't show up for me before I posted, because I hadn't refreshed.

Comment: I can accept that... Anyhow, your question has been closed.